# Getting "Sequence contains no elements" exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nhibernate, iqueryable

I am new to .net framework, nhibernate and iqueryable.

I have a um_user_login_count table which has 4 columns. They are id, login_ip, login_count and login_user_id.

Here is my UserLoginCount.cs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Project.UserManagement" namespace="Project.UserManagement.Domain" schema="UserManagement">
  <class name="UserLoginCount" table="um_user_login_count">
    <id name="Id" column="id" generator="identity" />
    <property name="Ip" column="login_ip" length="255" />
    <property name="Count" column="login_count" length="255" />
    <property name="UserId" column="login_user_id" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my LoginCount.cs file

```
namespace Project.UserManagement.Domain
{
    using System;
    using Iesi.Collections.Generic;
    using Project.ORM;

    public class UserLoginCount : UserManagementEntity<UserLoginCount>
    {
        public UserLoginCount() { }

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Ip { get; set; }
        public virtual string Count { get; set; }
        public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have declared in the UMDataService code

```
public static IQueryable<UserLoginCount> UserLoginCount
        {
            get
            {
                return DataServiceInstance.CurrentSession.Query<UserLoginCount>();
            }
        }
```

Here si the code from where I am called the service -

```
public string GetLoginInfo(string id)
        {
            UserLoginCount cnt = UMDataServices.UserLoginCount.Single();
            return cnt.Ip;
        }
```

Yet I am getting an error saying "Sequence contains no elements". I am absolutely new at this. I am not sure I have even asked the question properly.

Comment: Thank you guys for all of your answers. I still haven't found the solution to the problem. But when I find it I will answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UMDataServices.UserLoginCount.Single()` expects that there must be **exactly** 1 entry. In your case, there is no entry and the exception is thrown as expected.

There are other options: [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx)(), [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx)(), [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909042(v=vs.90).aspx),...

You could choose one depending on your requirement.

Comment: But there is a lot of data in the database

Comment: @eddard.stark: there is a lot of data but there could be something wrong with your query returning no data.

Comment: how can I find out the query?

Comment: I have used First and the exception is the same

Comment: @eddard.stark: In your case, there is no record, so First also throws exception.

Comment: @eddard.stark: First is different from Single is that there could be more than 1 record and First takes the first one. If there is no record, First throws exception.

Comment: I am looking at the database, there are 100s of data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71012/discussion-between-khanh-to-and-eddard-stark).

Answer (score 1):

This line `UserLoginCount cnt = UMDataServices.UserLoginCount.Single();`

is probably the culprit. You could change it to `SingleOrDefault` and check for null.

```
UserLoginCount cnt = UMDataServices.UserLoginCount.SingleOrDefault();
if(cnt != null) { /*do stuff */}
```

Comment: But there is a lot of data in the database

Comment: @eddard.stark they may be but your query refers to "CurrentSession" are they rows that match that?

Answer (score 1):

[`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534800%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) throws an exception under following circumstances:

**ArgumentNullException**

- source or predicate is null.

**InvalidOperationException**

- No element satisfies the condition in predicate
- More than one element satisfies the condition in predicate.
- The source sequence is empty.

You can prevent it with `SingleOrDefault`.

```
 UserLoginCount cnt = UMDataServices.UserLoginCount.SingleOrDefault();
 string ip = null;
 if(cnt != null)
      ip = cnt.Ip;
 return ip;
```

Comment: But there is a lot of data in the database